# Do you have any function or tools to convert simple html to special code which I like?

Tags: html, function

I want to convert a simple code to an special code which I like. see this simple code :

```
<html>
    <body>
         <a href="stack.com"> The content of the document </a> 
    </body>
</html>
```

convert to :

```
<html>\n\t<body>\n\t\t <a href=\"stack.com\"> The content of the document </a> \n\t</body>\n</html>
```

(convert linebreak to \n ; convert tabs to \t ; convert " to \")
And finally put them in one line. just one line.
Can you suggest me a good function or tools for this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to come into mind is **Notepad++** for me.

In **Macro** menu

> 1. You can start recording your actions
> 2. Replace all linebreaks with \n
> 3. Replace all tabs with \t
> 4. Replace all " with \"
> 5. And save your macro to use whenever you want to use again

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: @Mahmoodjavadzadeh Once you do it and save it for the first time, all the following ones are gonna be very simple :)